# Angular 6 -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your time.

Apparently, without realizing it, I must have updated something in the Angular libraries because the code has stopped working and now I am faced with the following error:

core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
at SafeSubscriber._next (informes.component.ts:166:77)**
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:22:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:89:1)
at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28:1)
at push../src/app/informes/informes.component.ts.Informes.ngOnInit (informes.component.ts:164:31)**`

which occurs exactly at this point in the code:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
 
 this.rutaActiva.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
 this.inicializarParametrosRecibidos(param);
 
 this.informesService.getInformes(this.rutaActiva.snapshot.queryParams).subscribe(result => { ...
```

The complete function is this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.rutaActiva.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
      this.informesService.getInformes(this.rutaActiva.snapshot.queryParams).subscribe(result => {

        if (param.busPorTipoDeInforme.toString() == "notificacion"){
          this.contratosFiltrados = result;
        }else{
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(result);
          window.open(fileURL, '_black');
        }

      }
        , error => {
          console.error('Error llamando a getInformes():', error);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('La ejecución de getInformes() terminó correctamente.');
        }
        )
    });
```

and the function it calls is this:

```
  public getInformes(filtro: any): Observable<any> {
      let params = new HttpParams();
      for(let parametro in filtro) {
          params.set(parametro, filtro[parametro]);
      }
      
      let opciones = new RequestOptions({
          search: params
      });
        
      let sUrl : string = environment.urlAplicacion + CONS_ACCIONES_SERVICIOS.ACCION_SERVICE_GET_INFORMES_NOTIF_VTOS;


      if (bBusXNotifDeVtos){
        return this.http.get(sUrl, {params: params}).pipe(map((response)  => {
          return response;
              }),catchError(error => this.tratarError(error))
        );
      }else{
        return this.http.get(sUrl, {params: params, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'}).pipe(map(
          (response) => {
          return new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' })
              }),catchError(error => this.tratarError(error))
        );
      }
    }
 }
```

That is, I define an observable function that depending on a parameter returns a PDF or another object. But this now with the new version does not work for me due to the error mentioned at the beginning.

And if I try to adapt the function in the following way:

```
  crearObservableGetInformes(filtro: any): Observable<Object> {
    return new Observable<Object>((observer) => {
      let params = new HttpParams();
      for(let parametro in filtro) {
          params.set(parametro, filtro[parametro]);
      }
      
      let opciones = new RequestOptions({
          search: params
      });
        
      let sUrl : string = environment.urlAplicacion + CONS_ACCIONES_SERVICIOS.ACCION_SERVICE_GET_INFORMES_NOTIF_VTOS;


      if (bBusXNotifDeVtos){
        return this.http.get(sUrl, {params: params}).pipe(map((response)  => {
          return response;
              }),catchError(error => this.tratarError(error))
        );
      }else{
        return this.http.get(sUrl, {params: params, responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'}).pipe(map(
          (response) => {
          return new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' })
              }),catchError(error => this.tratarError(error))
        );
      }
    }
 }
```

I get an error in the following code that I show in bold:

return new Observable(**(observer) => {**

and this is the error description:

```
Argument of type '(this: Observable<Object>, observer: Subscriber<Object>) => Observable<Object>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<Object>, subscriber: Subscriber<Object>) => TeardownLogic'.
  Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.
    Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'Observable<Object>' but required in type 'Unsubscribable'.ts(2345)
```

In short, I find myself with code that is productive that I cannot work with and that I cannot find a way to correct. Could someone help me please?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to return observables in this "crearObservableGetInformes" method because you have added the response type "Observable"

like this, you can change according to your code :

```
 observer.next(Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved part of the problem, specifically the error

> Argument of type '(this: Observable, observer:
> Subscriber) => Observable' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(this: Observable, subscriber:
> Subscriber) => TeardownLogic'.   Type 'Observable' is
> not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.
> Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'Observable' but required in type 'Unsubscribable'.ts(2345)

this way:

```
    observer.next(this.http.get(sUrl, {params: params}).pipe(map((response)  => {
        observer.next(response);
            }),catchError(error => this.tratarError(error))
      ));
```

but I still have the problem:

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.informesService.getInformes(...) is undefined
    ngOnInit informes.component.ts:166
    RxJS 6
```

That is, after trying to call the function in a different way, the problem persists.